# Connecting to another MySQL table OOP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I followed on online tutorial to create an OOP login/registration system for my website. I am trying to reuse the code to connect to the same database but a different table. The code below is the method to update the users table.

```
public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

        if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
            $id = $this->data()->id;    
        }

        if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem updating.');
        }
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is update any table using the same code.

I have tried changing 'users' to $table and then using declaring $table = 'destinations' in the relevant pages but get the errors " Undefined variable: table" and "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a problem updating.' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you use your method on subpages, but you should try below:

```
public function update($fields = array(), $id = null, $table = 'users') {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;    
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update($table, $id, $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem updating.');
    }
}
```

And method call:

```
$yourObject->update($fields, $id, 'table_to_update_name');
```